# Do you need Visual Studio 2010 to manage a 2010 build agent?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, tfs

we are considering TFS2010 but need to confirm some information as we're still using TFS2008 and vs2008. the question is whether we can still manage our builds using the 2008 client.

please advise.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create new build definitions, and then manage the builds (i.e. set build quality, retention policies, view build results, delete builds etc) all from the 2008 client.

You will need a 2010 client to edit the build definition or to configure the private build retention policies or take advantage of any other the other new features on the build definition (such as being able to control what is deleted when a build is deleted as part of a retention policy).

For comprehensive detail on what does and doesn't work see:

- [Compatibility Matrix for Team Foundation Server 2010 to Team Explorer 2008 and 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2009/10/19/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005.aspx)

Cheers,

Martin.